# Possibility of integrating secure elements with sensor networks?

Tags: security, sensors, cryptography

Assume we need to do a type of digital signature such as ECDSA with sensors used in sensor networks. So, is there a secure and possible approach to store the keys in these sensors?

For example, is it possible to integrate a secure element with these sensors to perform securely digital signature? Or maybe there is a better approach to do this?

Meanwhile, do we have energy problem for generating signatures? (Regarding to energy limitation of sensors.)

In general, is it logical to generate signatures with sensors? (Assume we need signing messages by sensors, because of security issues.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, any modern IoT endpoint software stack will support what you're looking for. I'm not sure that 'signed' is the most accurate way to describe this, but encrypted messaging is a basic requirement. The messaging encryption is likely to use TLS, but you need at least to ensure:

- Firmware is 'trusted'
- Over the Air firmware updates are possible, and trusted
- Firmware can't be rolled-back to an earlier version
- Devices have secure certificate stores
- Device certificates can be blacklisted if individual devices become suspect
- Devices only connect to trusted servers

Finally, if you need to ask these questions, you really need to find a supplier who you can trust rather than trying to [roll your own](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1517). Unless the whole stack is reasonably secure, you're pretty much wasting your own time by adding a token partial solution.