# Are there standardized MQTT topics?

Tags: mqtt, communication, mosquitto

I am new to MQTT (and home automation in general, I am much more in the systems and dev side), flashed a WiFi switch (Sonoff Basic), connected it to an instance of Mosquitto and Home Assistant and so far everything works fine.

When monitoring the Mosquitto bus, I see all kind of messages, such as

```
tele/hass1/LWT Online
tele/home/room1/switch1/LWT Online
cmnd/home/room1/switch1/POWER OFF
```

I recognize `home/room1/switch1` which I defined on my WiFi switch, and the switch then sent some topics prefixed by `cmnd` (command? that would be surprising as nobody manipulated the switch) and `tele` (telemetry?). `tele/hass1/...` is generated by Home Assistant.

**Are there any standards or commonly accepted practices for the prefixes?**

The MQTT documentation explains [how topics are formatted](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718106) but does not introduce any structure (except for topics beginning with `$`) so I guess that, best case, it would rather be a best practice (or practice full stop).

Comment: You do score points for not starting your topics with a leading `/`, this is just wrong as it adds a extra null segment to the topic tree which is not needed and makes it slightly harder to use wildcards properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In general, no — there aren't any standards for topic naming beyond the MQTT specifications**.

There are [plenty of opinions](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices) about how you should construct your MQTT topics, and [not a lot of fixed rules](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/966/12). While this is a bit unsettling when you'd like to know exactly what the best practice is, the lack of strict rules does mean you get a lot of flexibility with an MQTT broker.

As you're using Home Assistant, this narrows things down a bit, but more specifically, the topics you're looking at are specific to your Sonoff switch. The API is described [in this wiki](https://github.com/arendst/Sonoff-Tasmota/wiki/MQTT-Overview):

> - **Message**: cmnd
>
>   - **Issued by**: devices shown on the right hand side
>   - **Intent**: control the Sonoff; set configuration; ask for status
> - **Message**: stat
>
>   - **Issued by**: the Sonoffs on the left hand side
>   - **Intent**: report back status or configuration message
> - **Message**: tele
>
>   - **Issued by**: some Sonoffs (like temperature measuring devices)
>   - **Intent**: report unsolicited telemetry info at periodic intervals

The diagram referred to is [here](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/0533face4144436d30d7902480afd969c7fad276/687474703a2f2f616c742e70626569726e652e636f6d2f696d616765732f736f6e6f66665f636d6e645f666c6f77322e706e67), although it is best viewed in the wiki page linked above.

*In general*, any hierarchy used will be manufacturer or system specific; Sonoff devices will generally follow a documented MQTT topic structure, and other manufacturers might use something different. Not all manufacturers will document their products well (or at all!) — so take care when buying products.